# Facebook Events Widget

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I'm using the Facebook Events Widget in a Wordpress install (3.5.1), which can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-events-widget/

The widget is supposed to show a list of events from a certain Facebook fan page. In the widget settings, you have to fill in the id of that page, the id of your Facebook app, and its app secret. I have created an app with my own personal profile (I couldn't find any way to do it with the fan page)

When I save the widget and visit my page, the following error is thrown:

```
Caught exception: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

And below an empty list with the message: There are no events.

Comment: You should address this to the developer of this plugin on the WordPress support forum. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook-events-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a missing or mis-configured SSL configuration.  To access the Facebook API you need to use a SSL connection for your call back URL.

Comment: I was thinking in that direction too, my server doesn't support SSL though... Thanks!